# iOS 11 double tap on image dismisses UIImagePickerController and presenter view controller

Tags: ios, swift, ios11

We have a photo picker made with `UIImagePickerController`.

When making **double** tap (instead of **one** tap) the photo from gallery.

- On iOS 10: `UIImagePickerController` is dismissed
- On iOS 11: `UIImagePickerController` is dismissed and presenting view controller is dismissed as well :0

Is it iOS 11 bug or we have to adjust something?

---

Our code:

```
  let vc = UIImagePickerController()
  vc.delegate = self
  vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
  vc.allowsEditing = false
  rootVC.present(vc, animated: true) // `rootVC` also presented modally.
```

Comment: I am also facing the same, probably BUG.

Comment: Solved it yet? Please update answer if yes

Comment: Use completion handler of dismiss method to do furter activity Eg     [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        [self saveImage:image];
    }];

Comment: We fixed by setting `delegate = nil` right after delegate call. See new answer below.

Comment: Setting the delegate nil doesn't seem to work on the device. The issue is didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo is called multiple times and thus if we use dismiss inside didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo,it is called multiple times leading to the issue

Comment: @amar Setting `completionHandler` to nil, or using private Bool variable as a flag to ignore sequential calls can be an option.

Comment: Still appears in iOS 14. I believe it's a bug in `UIImagePickerController`.

Answer (score 9):

Instead of self.dismiss(), use picker.dismiss()

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])
{
    //self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

This will only dismiss your picker view and not the view controller.

Comment: This actually didn't work for me as the delegate method doesn't seem to be called twice when a photo is double tapped. Rather, it appears that the image picker is dismissing itself. Specifically, if I comment  out `picker.dismiss...` it still dismisses the picker after calling the didSelectImage delegate method. Note: in my scenario the delegate is deallocated as a side effect of the initial call of the picker callback. The image picker controller might decide to dismiss itself during the double tap.

Comment: This indeed seems to be the case, as preventing the deallocation of the delegate prevents the picker from dismissing the presenting view controller.

Answer (score 3):

We end up with solution: Set `delegate = nil` right after delegate call in `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo`.

```
public class ImagePicker: NSObject {

   private lazy var viewController = setupActionSheet()
   private var rootViewController: UIViewController?
   private var completionHandler: (([String: Any]) -> Void)?
   private var cancellationHandler: (() -> Void)?
}

extension ImagePicker {

   public func present(on: UIViewController, completionHandler: @escaping (([String: Any]) -> Void)) {
      rootViewController = on
      self.completionHandler = completionHandler
      cancellationHandler = nil
      on.presentAnimated(viewController)
   }

   public func present(on: UIViewController,
                       completionHandler: @escaping (([String: Any]) -> Void),
                       cancellationHandler: @escaping (() -> Void)) {
      rootViewController = on
      self.completionHandler = completionHandler
      self.cancellationHandler = cancellationHandler
      on.presentAnimated(viewController)
   }
}

extension ImagePicker {

   private func setupActionSheet() -> UIAlertController {
      let actionSheet = UIAlertController(actionSheetWithTitle: LocalizedString.Generic.ImagePicker.addPhoto)

      if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera) {
         actionSheet.addDefaultAction(LocalizedString.Generic.ImagePicker.takePhoto) { [weak self] _ in
            self?.presentImagePicker(.camera)
         }
      }
      actionSheet.addDefaultAction(LocalizedString.Generic.ImagePicker.selectPhoto) { [weak self] _ in
         self?.presentImagePicker(.photoLibrary)
      }
      actionSheet.addCancelAction(LocalizedString.Generic.ButtonTitle.cancel) { [weak self] _ in
         self?.cancellationHandler?()
      }
      return actionSheet
   }

   private func presentImagePicker(_ sourceType: UIImagePickerControllerSourceType) {
      let vc = UIImagePickerController()
      vc.delegate = self
      vc.allowsEditing = false
      vc.sourceType = sourceType
      rootViewController?.present(vc, animated: true)
   }
}

extension ImagePicker: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

   public func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String: Any]) {
      picker.delegate = nil /// It prevents to call delegate when user taps on a few images very fast. seems iOS 11 issue only.
      if picker.sourceType == .camera, let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
         UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)
      }
      picker.dismiss(animated: true) {
         self.completionHandler?(info)
      }
   }

   public func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
      picker.dismiss(animated: true) {
         self.cancellationHandler?()
      }
   }
}
```

Usage:

```
  // Somewhere in view controller code.
  imagePicker = ImagePicker()
  imagePicker?.present(on: self) { [weak self] in
     self?.imagePicker = nil
     self?.viewModel.addImage($0)
  }
```

Comment: Are you calling dismiss for you `rootVC` in `completionHandler`'s callback?

Comment: We are `not` calling `dismiss for rootVC`. `dismiss` called only on `picker`. Example code updated.

Comment: On my side, this approach works on iOS13, while not on iOS15.